# Where can I get a list of all charsets (Content-Type HTTP response header)

Tags: character-encoding

[W3C says](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/references.html#ref-CHARSETS) there is a full list [here](ftp://ftp.isi.edu/in-notes/iana/assignments/character-sets), however it seems to be down.

Where can I get a list of them?

Answer (score 5):

I found a list at iana:

http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets

Answer (score -3):

I use the following list

http://webdesign.about.com/od/multimedia/a/mime-types-by-content-type.htm

Comment: Those are MIME-types, not charsets.

Comment: Sorry about that I sent the wrong link by mistake.  http://www.iana.org/assignments/character-sets is the best location as you posted.